# Gradient Descent for Multi-Level / Mixed / Hierarchical Regression Model

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, linear-regression, gradient-descent, multilevel-analysis

How would gradient descent work in a multilevel regression setting? This is fairly clear to me in a standard linear regression formulation, but haven't been able to wrap my head around parameter updates in hierarchical models.

In short, I'd like to be able to make sequential updates to an existing model in a online-ish format (we'll see new data every *t* timesteps, and would actually like to bias the updates towards newer observations but that's potentially another conversation), where the idea would be to have better informed parameter estimates over time. My thought was that hand-coding a gradient descent update step would be a potential solution, but need to figure out how this would work given the hierarchical structure of the data.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Interesting question, but off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. My advice is try to formulate the parameter adjustment as an exact (or as exact as you can make it) minimization problem instead of more or less random step. It's okay by me to weight recent data more heavily, but having done that, then find parameters by minimizing (via LBFGS or other approximately exact algorithm) over that weighted data set. (Maximum likelihood is easily generalizable for weighted data.)

Comment: As to calculating the gradient, you could use a computer algebra system for that. It is not a difficult algebra problem, just a matter of keeping track of all the i's and j's and p's and q's. I use Maxima a lot (https://maxima.sourceforge.io) but you could also try Sympy (https://sympy.org); there are many others which a web search will find. Good luck and have fun, sounds like a good problem.

Comment: This question is not a programming one. Figure out the maths behind your problem first and come back for programming issues if you have ones. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @RobertDodier, great insights and will take those forward.

I'll take this question to a better source as well, realize this is more theory than execution.